# Spring Retry for Dao Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, connection-pooling

I have the below code
Spring boot version  : 2.3.4

```
@Repository
class Dbrepository
{


public void performCall() {

 simpleJdbcCall = new 
               SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate) 
               .withProcedureName("read_actor")
             //.....
  
    simpleJdbcCall.execute(...) ;
}

}
```

I want to retry the performCall() atleast 3 times at interval of 1 min between each call.
How can i achieve this?
I am thinking of using Spring Retry ?Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding spring-retry

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Add `@EnableRetry` in your main application

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts=3,backoff=@Backoff(delay = 10000))
public void performCall() {

 simpleJdbcCall = new 
               SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate) 
               .withProcedureName("read_actor")
             //.....
  
    simpleJdbcCall.execute(...) ;
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: ```@EnableRetry``` annotation should be added to his ```@Configuration``` class.
How about placing the bloc below outside the retry function? 
```simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("read_actor")
```

Comment: I don't understand your question what do you mean about outside

Comment: Does he need to recreate  a ```SimpleJdbcCall```in every retry ?

Comment: @M.Mas. i have that alreadu in another method.Above code is just sample code

Comment: @A.khalifa how can i retry for just database connection issue and nothing else.Which exception should i mention

Comment: @PaleBlueDot Add try catch and add two function one in try without Retryable and in catch function add Retryable

Comment: how will 2 function help...I dont need 2 methods

Comment: so add 2 function help in your Dbrepository one for success connection and second for failure